# Opening CS:GO Sticker Capsules

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Do you need a key to open a CS:GO Sticker Capsule? I'm not talking about the old capsules like Sticker Capsule 1 or Sticker Capsule 2, I'm talking about the new capsules like the Autograph Capsule.

Answer (score 1):

No, the latest [PGL Stockholm 2021 Autograph Capsules](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/PGL_Stockholm_2021_Autograph_Capsules) do not need a key to open and neither do the recent sticker capsules. As far as I can tell from the [counterstrike fandom site](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Sticker_Capsules) none of the recent capsules need keys, only the following capsules require keys to be opened:

```
- Sticker Capsule
- Sticker Capsule 2
- Community Sticker Capsule 1
```